# PG_Restore local backup to docker container using pipe viewer

Tags: docker, terminal, pg-restore

I was using the following command to restore from a backup:

```
pv backup.sql.gz | gunzip | pg_restore -d $DBHOST
```

This was helpful because I can roughly see how far a long the backup has to finish.

I recently moved the DB into a docker container and wanted to be able to run the same restore, but have been struggling getting the command to work. I'm assuming I have to redirect the gunzip output somehow, but haven't been having any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you start the database container with a `-p ...:5432` option to publish its port to the host?  If so, you can use exactly the same command you're using now; you don't need to do anything Docker-specific.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, but the container/ports will vary, so won't know things like the password/port/username. Was hoping just to jump into the specified container and do it directly.

Comment: You get to pick the host port (the first `-p` number) and don't need to know any container-specific details beyond the DNS name of the host (`localhost` if the restore process is on the same host as the database container).  You'll always need to know the database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to expose the server ports, you can use

```
pv backup.sql.gz | gunzip | docker exec -i [container_name] pg_restore -d $DBHOST
```

This will open the `pg_restore` command within the running container and pipe into that process. Note the '-i' flag, it's important. Assuming your server container also has clients installed, but if not, I'd recommend you to do so anyway.

Typically, this is a pattern I use very often in scripts as well, even using SSH in between; this will all work transparently:

```
pv backup.sql.gz | gunzip | ssh some_ssh_host docker exec -i [container_name] pg_restore -d $DBHOST
```

Note that if you do this over SSH as well, it will start to make sense to decide where to execute your unzip:

```
pv backup.sql.gz | ssh some_ssh_host gunzip \| docker exec -i [container_name] pg_restore -d $DBHOST
```

Note that the pipe in that case needs to be escaped to send it as a literal to the `ssh` command.